# Why conditional operator is working only for false value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Conditional operator is only giving false thus only the second condition is working i.e background-color: orange, color: white. What is wrong with this code?(in col-4).

```js
import React from 'react';
import './ListData.css';

function ListData({customer:{id, name, price, stock_quantity, manufacturer, date_added, date_modified} }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <li class="table-row">
                <div class="col col-1" data-label="Id">{id}</div>
                <div class="col col-2" data-label="Name">{name}</div>
                <div class="col col-3" data-label="Price">$ {price}</div>
                <div class="col col-4" data-label="Quantity" style={{stock_quantity}>=50 ? {backgroundColor: 'green', color: 'white'}: {backgroundColor: 'orange', color: 'white'}}>{stock_quantity}</div>
                <div class="col col-5" data-label="Manufacturer">{manufacturer}</div>
                <div class="col col-6" data-label="Date Added">{date_added}</div>
                <div class="col col-7" data-label="Date Modified">{date_modified}</div>
            </li>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ListData
```

{stock_quantity} is giving me the value if not put under style.

Comment: Did you mean `stock_quantity >= 50`…?

Comment: `{}` is to interpolate expressions into the HTML template. You don't need another `{}` inside the expression. Inside `{}`, it has the same meaning as `{stock_quantity}` in Javascript, which is shorthand for `{stock_quantity: stock_quantity}`. In other words, you're constructing an object and check whether it is `>= 50`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the brackets when u said stock_quantity

```
import React from 'react';
import './ListData.css';

function ListData({customer:{id, name, price, stock_quantity, manufacturer, date_added, date_modified} }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <li class="table-row">
                <div class="col col-1" data-label="Id">{id}</div>
                <div class="col col-2" data-label="Name">{name}</div>
                <div class="col col-3" data-label="Price">$ {price}</div>
                <div class="col col-4" data-label="Quantity" 
  style=
  {stock_quantity >=50 ? {backgroundColor: 'green', color: 'white'}: {backgroundColor: 'orange', color: 'white'}}


>{stock_quantity}</div>
                <div class="col col-5" data-label="Manufacturer">{manufacturer}</div>
                <div class="col col-6" data-label="Date Added">{date_added}</div>
                <div class="col col-7" data-label="Date Modified">{date_modified}</div>
            </li>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ListData
```